# Corrupted data best practice

Tags: analytics, data-warehouse, data-cleaning

I have been hearing a lot recently that it is good practice to replace corrupted values by 999999 or similar values that are out of the normal range of value of the underlying data field.

It sounds to me that this is complete madness and necessarily leads to mistake for novice users when they later on plug in their Tableau or other analytics to the data warehouse.

I actually see no rationale application for this method.

What's your view on this?

Comment: If there isn't much bad data, it doesn't make a material difference, you're on a tight schedule, and there is no one actively looking after data in the business it's actually a good idea. Although I've certainly never replaced data with a made up number like that - always something that clearly indicates it's incorrect, i.e. the 'unknown' dimesnion member.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to measures that will be used in aggregations and calculations, I would definitely not recommend replacing their values with higher or out of range values, replacing the values with NULLs is more appropriate in this case since it will not corrupt the results.

When it come to dimensions and textual descriptions, the best approach would be to have a line in your dimension table to describe "unknown" or "na" value and have an ID join with the fact table.

Comment: I fully agree with you; this is what I do and I would except anybody with OK SQL knowledge to be able to do anything he/she wants with the data afterwards..

Comment: The problem with NULL in numeric fields is that an analytics or reporting tool - or end user - might interpret it as zero. This can result in incorrect aggregates; consider the implication for any averages, for instance. Clearly incorrect figures as asked about aren't by any means a complete solution, but they may actually be less risky than leaving a NULL in a numeric field.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately true that some of the projects use a very high value which is supported by the system and something impossible through the normal channel (business) to enter in case of a corrupted record (poor data quality) or orphan record (records without supporting attributes).

But we always filter these records out in the presentation layer to avoid confusing the end users.

Alternatively you could do use negative numbers instead of very high numbers. But the logic should be same where we need to filter these records out in the presentation layer. This way we can retrospectively correct these records in the future and they are easily identified with a filter.